# Blogs Standard URL Filter /Tagged/Tag Not Working - Shopify

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid, blogs

I added the following code to create a filter for blogs

```
{%- for tag in blog.all_tags -%}
    <a
      class="button button--small {% if current_tags contains tag %} button--solid {% else %} button--outline {% endif %}"
      href="{{ blog.url }}/tagged/{{ tag | handleize }}"
    >
      {{ tag | capitalize }}
    </a>
{%- endfor -%}
```

I also tried {{ tag.handle }} instead of {{ tag | handleize }}

However blogs aren't filtered as intended, I searched for JavaScript code that could affect the filter's functionality but didn't find any

When I headed to the online store => navigation I saw this message "The current theme doesn’t support filters." however after searching it should not affect the blogs filter it's only for the products filter

And I ensured the URL format was working by trying the same URL on an old theme where the blogs got filtered correctly

Are there any other steps to take to debug this issue?